# Lines that have three upper case characters in parenthesis like (LTI) - remember to escape certain characters :)

Tags: postgresql

In this assignment you will create a regular expression to retrieve a subset data from the purpose column of the taxdata table in the readonly database (access details below). Write a regular expressions to retrieve that meet the following criteria:

Lines that have three upper case characters in parenthesis like (LTI) - remember to escape certain characters :)

Lines that have three upper case characters in parenthesis like (LTI) - remember to escape certain characters :)

Comment: Your question doesn't yet contain a question. And I doesn't include the important "This is what I have tried so far" section. Once you include that, someone may be able to assist. (It should also get tagged as homework.)

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve. See also [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).